# Laravel search with join method

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I try to search in my app in Post titles and post tags at the same time so I'm using join method in my search function.

here is my form:

```
<div class="search">
      <form class="form-inline" action="/search" method="GET" role="search">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        <div class="field-toggle">
          <input type="text" name="search" class="search-form" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search...">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="button">search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

And this is my function:

```
public function search() {

  $search = request('search');

  $foods = Food::join('food_ingredient', 'food_ingredient.food_id','=', 'food.id')
         ->join('ingredients','ingredient.id','=','food_ingredient.ingredient.id')
         ->where('food.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
         ->orWhere('ingredient.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%') //The fix
         ->orderBy('food.created_at', 'desc')
         ->groupBy('food.id')
         ->with('ingredients')
         ->paginate(8);

  return view('front.search', compact('foods'));
}
```

With this i'm getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'food.title' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `foods` inner
>   join `food_ingredient` on `food_ingredient`.`food_id` = `food`.`id`
>   inner join `ingredients` on `ingredient`.`id` =
>   `food_ingredient`.`ingredient`.`id` where `food`.`title` LIKE %papper%
>   or `ingredient`.`title` LIKE %papper% group by `food`.`id`)

This is how is my database:

> Foods ->store posts
>
> Ingredients ->Store ingredients
>
> Food_ingredient ->store posts tags

[image: 1][image: 2]

How can I fix it?

PS: my post names are `food` and my tags name are `ingredient` (just different naming).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When using joins you need to specify in the `where` clause the table name as well because after `joins` you will have multiple columns, so you need to specify the table name when asking the `title`:

```
  $foods = Food::join('food_ingredient', 'food_ingredient.food_id','=', 'food.id')
         ->join('ingredients','ingredient.id','=','food_ingredient.ingredient.id')
         ->where('ingredient.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%') ...
```

Assuming you want to search for ingredient title

Comment: You should change the where clause to fit your needs, as stated I assumed you wanted to search by `ingredtient.title`...maybe `ingredients.name`? This depends on what you want to achieve

Comment: `ingredtient.title` and `food.title` I changed the part you mentioned also my error. (still getting error)

Comment: You had in the beginning a search based on 2 titles (in the original question as well), you need to specify the tables...that's it ! I cannot guess what you need or what logic you want to implement because I do not know for instance your table structure nor what SQL you want to generate by using Eloquent

Comment: I mentioned all in my question please read it,  `This is how is my database:

Foods ->store posts

Ingredients ->Store ingredients

Food_ingredient ->store posts tags
`

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose wild card in comma so to search the param it would be like

```
public function searchOrders($param)
{
    $id = "id";
    $search='%'.$param.'%';

    $orders = DB::select('SELECT o.*,s.name,b.name FROM orders o JOIN users b on o.buyer_id= b.id JOIN users s on o.seller_id=s.id where o.id LIKE  ?', [$search]);

    $data = array(
        "orders" => $orders
    );
    return View('admin.orders.service_search_orders', $data);
}
```